# Auto click on Update button on Google Play store

Tags: android

Is there a way to auto-click on the Update button when the user is redirected to the play store when there is an update?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK No. You can bound the user to use the app with a upgrade dialog inside app .

Comment: Can we auto start the app update as soon as it is available by any means?

Comment: No its not possible,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to auto-click on the Update button when the user is redirected to the play store when there is an update?

No, But you can call an api on splash screen that tell you latest version of app, then check it, and restrict use of app without update.

Show an dialog to ask user "you need to update your application" when ok pressed, you can redirect user to playstore app page. Where he will find update option.

This is how you redirect user

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // package name of the app
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Khemraj... Yes we are going to implement this as you have mentioned but just we wanted to explore if that auto-click thing was possible.... Thanks for your help....

Comment: Currently we can not perform actions to another app.

Comment: You can try something like - Check if there's an Update on Splash Screen, navigate to PlayStore if there's one available... :) But you cannot Control the Auto-Click of 'Update Button' on PlayStore

Comment: @Khemraj, That is not the solution... The code will just give broadcast after the app is updated.... :)